# console based JSON API configuration over relational database

Tags: json, rest, deployd

I've been looking for a tool/utility that provides a console-like option for building JSON data APIs on top of a relational database.

I've come across deployd (http://deployd.com/) and emergent one (http://www.emergentone.com/), and am wondering if there is anythign similar for internal relational Dbs.

Success would be the ability to configure rather than program the APIs exposing data.

Comment: I'm been looking at slashDb (http://www.slashdb.com/) and will be evaluating Esspresso Logic (http://www.espressologic.com/) shortly.

Comment: With /db entire database content becomes addressable by URLs and can be output in JSON, XML, CSV and HTML. You can browse through data and grab the links you need in your app or API. It is super easy to work with. Contact us through the website and we will hook you up with a product walk-through and/or your own demo instance. Just mention this page.

Answer (score 0):

Deployd for now works only on MongoDB (non-relational), so I guess it is not the one you are looking for. You could check out [Django Rest Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) though, I haven't used it but it might be the one that you are looking for.